# npm install doesn't create node_modules folder in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

After `docker build .` command `RUN npm install` and `RUN npm run production` console write: `npm files successfully compiled`, but actually compiled files are not created and node_modules folder does not exist in WORKDIR. Possible run this command in docker container for compile scripts? And is it correct if I compile it in a docker container?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
#COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libonig-dev libpq-dev \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev
    
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install npm

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY ./www /var/www
ARG CACHE_DATE=not_a_date
RUN npm install
RUN npm run production

COPY ./www /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www ./www /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

Comment: please add package.json file or at least `npm run production` meaning in the package.json file. also, how do you confirm the node_modules folder is not being created? what seems to be the issue that made you ask the question about the folder?

Comment: npm run production -  works fine, and all files compiled, but files not created.
And in not docker container all forks fine, i think problem with docker.
Why after npm install not exist node_modules file? I think problem with volumes and mounting. I check with command "ls" and node_modules not exist, and compiled files too.

Comment: Is `npm run production` like `npm run build`? how do you know they compiled successfuly? what volumes are you checking and how (literal command and checking process)? please update your question with this information so I can help you faster and better

Comment: Yes, it like `build` command. Im checking console output when execution `npm run production` and this output same when im run this command outside the container. And output show success result after this command, but files not created.

Comment: ok, please if possible add the terminal output. how are you checking for the files existens?

Comment: Im use "ls" in console of conatiner. Thats all.
Output:
`/var/www/node_modules/#`

Comment: It looks like you're copying the files from your local machine multiple times after you run the `npm install` command.  If `node_modules` exists locally and is empty, you're just overwriting what you have in the image when you copy after running the install command.  I would suggest doing the COPY instruction just once and give it permissions to the `www` user there

Answer (score 0):

I think you coping data from www multiple times and also after `npm install`, so it may be replacing the `node_modules` folder, So I changed your Dockerfile

 new Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
#COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libonig-dev libpq-dev \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev
    
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install npm

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY ./www /var/www
ARG CACHE_DATE=not_a_date
RUN npm install
RUN npm run production


# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www ./www /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I made docker-entrypoint.sh file and write all commands in this file.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I added line to Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT ./docker-entrypoint.sh and in ./docker-entrypoint.sh run `npm install` command